# Div блок вылазит за границы страницы

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

Доброго времени суток всем. Имеется код, в нем по нажатию на кнопку копируется скрытый текст. По наведению на кнопку, с помощью других пользователей теперь высвечивается скрытый текст. Поработал со стилями, чтобы все было красиво на вид, все выводится, все отлично.Но вот незадача, у крайних элементов, блок div вылазит за края, ни как не могу это исправить уже по-всякому пробовал, но не получается( Просьба навести в нужное русло. Код ниже:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">    
 <title>ТЕКСТ</title>
 
 <style type="text/css">
 html{
  font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block}audio,canvas,progress,video{display:inline-block;vertical-align:baseline}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden],template{display:none}a{background:transparent}a:active,a:hover{outline:0}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}b,strong{font-weight:700}dfn{font-style:italic}h1{font-size:2em;margin:.67em 0}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sup{top:-.5em}sub{bottom:-.25em}img{border:0}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}figure{margin:1em 40px}hr{-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;height:0}pre{overflow:auto}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{color:inherit;font:inherit;margin:0}button{overflow:visible}button,select{text-transform:none}button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer}button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default}button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}input{line-height:normal}input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}fieldset{border:1px solid silver;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em}legend{border:0;padding:0}textarea{overflow:auto}optgroup{font-weight:700}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}td,th{padding:0}
 body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
  text-align: left;
 }
 

 </style>
 
<script src="http://www.net-f.ru/primer/clipboard/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head> <body style="font-size: 14px; position: relative; padding: 0;">
<p align="center">ТЕКСТ</p>
 <table class="table">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
      
<td class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст">ТЕКСТ <div class="info"></div></td>
<td class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст">ТЕКСТ <div class="info"></div></td>
<td class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст">ТЕКСТ <div class="info"></div></td>
<td class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст">ТЕКСТ <div class="info"></div></td>
<td class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст">ТЕКСТ <div class="info"></div></td>
<td class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст">ТЕКСТ <div class="info"></div></td>
<td class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст">ТЕКСТ <div class="info"></div></td>
<td class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст">ТЕКСТ <div class="info"></div></td>
<td class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст">ТЕКСТ <div class="info"></div></td>



</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<style type="text/css">
p {
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #00838f;
}

.btn { position: relative; }

.info { 
 position: absolute;
 border: 3px solid #FFDEAD;
 display: inline-table;
 background: #158078; 
 text-indent: 0px;
 cursor: progress;
 width: 300px;  
 left: 0em; 
 top: 3em;
 line-height: 1.5;
 z-index:9999
 }
 
  
  .table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;
 }
 .table th, .table td {
     border: 1px solid;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #cbdfef;
 }

 /* Hover */
 .table td:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px; 
  bottom: 0px;    
  left: 0px;
  border: 3px solid #ffe5c5;
  border-radius: 7px;
  
 }

 /* Click */
 .table td.active:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px; 
  bottom: 0px;    
  left: 0px;
  border: 3px solid orange !important;
  border-radius: 7px;
 }
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.table th, .table td').click(function(){
  $('.table td').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
 });
});
</script>

<script>
var cb = new Clipboard('.btn'); // класс кнопки
cb.on('success', function(e){
        // уведомление, можно настроить своё
        // выделение скопированного текста на 1,5 секунды
 window.setTimeout(function(){e.clearSelection();}, 1500);
});
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.table th, .table td').click(function(){
   $('.table td').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
  });

  $(".btn").on('mouseover', function() {
   $(this).children(".info").text($(this).attr("data-clipboard-text"));
  });

  $(".btn").on('mouseout', function() {
   $(this).children(".info").text("");
  });
 });
  
  var cb = new Clipboard('.btn'); // класс кнопки
 cb.on('success', function(e){
  window.setTimeout(function(){
   console.log(true);
   e.clearSelection();
  }, 1500);
 });
</script>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
        var dv = document.getElementById("info");
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В зависимости от того, где это будет использоваться, и будет ли эта разметка иметь все столько же элементов сколько сейчас, или же они будут как то генерироваться.

Можно попробовать просто элементам которые вылазят за края, через `"nth-child"` добавить противоположное значение (выравнивание по правому краю, а не по левому), тогда они не будут выходить за контейнер.

Но это не гибкое решение, думаю лучше всего написать js который будет все это отслеживать.
Пример с nth-child:

```
td.btn:nth-child(6n) .info {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
```

// ваш пример но с (nth-child)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">    
 <title>ТЕКСТ</title>
 
 <style type="text/css">
 html{
  font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block}audio,canvas,progress,video{display:inline-block;vertical-align:baseline}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden],template{display:none}a{background:transparent}a:active,a:hover{outline:0}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}b,strong{font-weight:700}dfn{font-style:italic}h1{font-size:2em;margin:.67em 0}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sup{top:-.5em}sub{bottom:-.25em}img{border:0}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}figure{margin:1em 40px}hr{-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;height:0}pre{overflow:auto}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{color:inherit;font:inherit;margin:0}button{overflow:visible}button,select{text-transform:none}button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer}button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default}button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}input{line-height:normal}input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}fieldset{border:1px solid silver;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em}legend{border:0;padding:0}textarea{overflow:auto}optgroup{font-weight:700}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}td,th{padding:0}
 body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
  text-align: left;
 }
 

 </style>
 
<script src="http://www.net-f.ru/primer/clipboard/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head> <body style="font-size: 14px; position: relative; padding: 0;">
<p align="center">ТЕКСТ</p>
 <table class="table">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
      
<td class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст">ТЕКСТ <div class="info"></div></td>
<td class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст">ТЕКСТ <div class="info"></div></td>
<td class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст">ТЕКСТ <div class="info"></div></td>
<td class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст">ТЕКСТ <div class="info"></div></td>
<td class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст">ТЕКСТ <div class="info"></div></td>
<td class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст">ТЕКСТ <div class="info"></div></td>
<td class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст">ТЕКСТ <div class="info"></div></td>
<td class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст">ТЕКСТ <div class="info"></div></td>
<td class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст">ТЕКСТ <div class="info"></div></td>



</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<style type="text/css">
p {
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #00838f;
}

.btn { position: relative; }

.info { 
 position: absolute;
 border: 3px solid #FFDEAD;
 display: inline-table;
 background: #158078; 
 text-indent: 0px;
 cursor: progress;
 width: 300px;  
 left: 0em; 
 top: 3em;
 line-height: 1.5;
 z-index:9999
 }
 
  
  .table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;
 }
 .table th, .table td {
     border: 1px solid;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #cbdfef;
 }

 /* Hover */
 .table td:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px; 
  bottom: 0px;    
  left: 0px;
  border: 3px solid #ffe5c5;
  border-radius: 7px;
  
 }

 /* Click */
 .table td.active:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px; 
  bottom: 0px;    
  left: 0px;
  border: 3px solid orange !important;
  border-radius: 7px;
 }
  
  /* nth-child */
  
  td.btn:nth-child(6n) .info,
  td.btn:nth-child(7n) .info,
  td.btn:nth-child(8n) .info,
  td.btn:nth-child(9n) .info,
  td.btn:nth-child(10n) .info {
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
    }
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.table th, .table td').click(function(){
  $('.table td').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
 });
});
</script>

<script>
var cb = new Clipboard('.btn'); // класс кнопки
cb.on('success', function(e){
        // уведомление, можно настроить своё
        // выделение скопированного текста на 1,5 секунды
 window.setTimeout(function(){e.clearSelection();}, 1500);
});
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.table th, .table td').click(function(){
   $('.table td').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
  });

  $(".btn").on('mouseover', function() {
   $(this).children(".info").text($(this).attr("data-clipboard-text"));
  });

  $(".btn").on('mouseout', function() {
   $(this).children(".info").text("");
  });
 });
  
  var cb = new Clipboard('.btn'); // класс кнопки
 cb.on('success', function(e){
  window.setTimeout(function(){
   console.log(true);
   e.clearSelection();
  }, 1500);
 });
</script>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
        var dv = document.getElementById("info");
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Благодарю вас! Да, это решение хорошо подходит, то что нужно практически. Но вы верно подметили, что элементы  будут генерироваться новые. Планируется увеличение таблицы, 10 элементов в строке, в низ может быть 10 и более строк, постоянно будет пополняться. Примерно принцип работы понял, спасибо вам за ответ!

Comment: Следовательно, теперь с правой частью все отлично, это радует) Как я понял, когда элементы дойдут до низа страницы, то это уже не пройдет, тогда нужно будет script. Хотя кажется, понял, что это же самое можно будет прописать например для 10 строки и далее, только с переносом в верх)

Answer (score 1):

### CSS

> ВНИМАНИЕ
>   не претендую на правильность подхода, его работоспособность и вообще, это всё мои личные фантазии на ночь

```
.sticky {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    background-color: #dc9934;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```css
.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  background-color: #dc9934;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 1500px;
}

.box:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #34dcb514;
}

.ho .sticky {
  display: none;
}

.ho:hover .sticky {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><h2>ниже</h2></div>
<div class="box">
  qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas <br> qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas <br> qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas <br>
  <span style="position: relative; left: 150px;">
  <span class="sticky"> sticky stickystickystickystickysticky sticky sticky stickystickysticky</span>
  </span>
  qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas <br> qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas <br> qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas <br>
</div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="box ho" style="min-width: 450px;">
    <h2>наведи мышку</h2>
    qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas <br> qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas <br> qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas <br>
    <span style="position: relative; left: 150px;">
   <span class="sticky"> sticky stickystickystickystickysticky sticky sticky stickystickysticky</span>
    </span>
    qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas <br> qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas <br> qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas qqqwa sadas <br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

[тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17680031/4794368) есть ещё один способ на css, но в том примере текст может уйти ниже, что приводит к появлению прокрутки

### JavaScrip

написать скрипт используя:

- рабочая область - `window.innerWidth` `window.innerHeight`
- позиция и габариты "кнопки"

  ```
  var el: HTMLElement;
  const { top, left, width, height } = el.getBoundingClientRect()
  ```

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ! Изначально хотел использовать getBoundingClientRect, но ни как не смог с ним разобраться, как применять, на вашем примере и примере ниже попробую решить задачу, спасибо вам!